# AngularJS filter to concat objects into single array of objects

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have my ng-repeat returning arrays like the ones below:

```
[{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}]
[{"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}]
```

I'd like to create a filter to combine the arrays into one array so that I can use an orderBy | 'day'.

```
[
{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"},
    {"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"
}]
```

I have a filter used to filter my overall object, but the logic here is much simpler, I'm not sure how to tweak the filter I have to concatenate these objects.

```
angular.module('hcApp')
.filter('combine', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var temp = [];
    var result = temp.concat.apply(temp,items.map(function(itm){ 
      return temp.concat.apply(temp, Object(itm).map(function(key){ 
       return itm.year[key]; 
  }));
}));  
    return result;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since the data comes as array of arrays 2D and to flatten it out, you could just perform a `concat` on your filter.

```
angular.module('hcApp')
.filter('combine', function() {
  return function(items) {
     return [].concat.apply([],items)
          .sort(function(a,b){ return +a.day < b.day ? -1 : 1; });//and add sort as well probably
  };
});
```

**[Bin](http://jsbin.com/zijonivisoto/5/edit)**

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help. Not working for some reason, but it seems like it should be. I'll put a Bin together

Comment: @byrdr did it work for u. Saw another question from u. If u have an issue can u post a working plunk il try to help

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the filter to work with my setup even though the resulting array appeared the same as the one in the Bin, which did work with your filter in my view. I'll put a plunkr together

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use `.push()` to join them together. Since each of your returning arrays consist of 1 element, you will need to access the first element of each data, and the push it to another final array.

```
  var some_data_1 = [{"day":"10","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}];
  var some_data_2 = [{"day":"3","title":"day","summary":"summary","description":"ok","_id":"53f25185bffedb83d8348b22"}] ;

  var temp = [];
  //push the first element(the only element) in the returning arrays
  temp.push(some_data_1[0], some_data_2[0]);
```

Here is the working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/t5zRAYmobyYqkEKhrGTd?p=preview